# How to combine two phrases in one sentences

Tags: phrase-request

I have a type of dependency between variables. I would like to express that the type of dependency can be set to one or a set of different patterns.

> The types of dependency patterns are almost limited to a set of various dependencies or fixed to one single type.

I feel that my sentence is not correct and not understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be better, expresses one choice out of two.

> The types of dependency patterns are almost limited to **either** a set of various dependencies **or** fixed to one single type.

As suggested in the comment, another solution sounds even better (I wander if meaning is the same - probably not):

> The types of dependency patterns are **either** almost limited to a set of various dependencies **or** fixed to one single type.

Comment: That sentence has a problem as it's written. If you put **either** where you did, then both things that come after it are limited to something. But you use **fixed** after *or*, which would imply *limited fixed*. To correct the sentence, you need to move **either** back: *The types of dependency patterns are* ***either*** *almost limited to a set of various dependencies* ***or*** *fixed to one single type.*

Comment: @Jason: updated the answer. Thanks ;) In my solution, there is a hint that another alternative (or more) may exist. In your solution, there are strictly two alternatives.